# Paint faces depending on count of vertices

Tags: materials, vertices, geometry-nodes, faces, color

There is a sphere which have faces with different count of vertices (3,4,5,6). I need to paint those faces on different colors depending on the number of vertices using geometry nodes. If number of vertices is changing, colour should also change.

For example: 3 vertices - red material. 4 vertices - blue material. Etc.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with this node setup:

[image]

these materials:

[image]

you will get:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

*Just to add another small piece to the range of possibilities:*

This variant captures the number of vertices in *Geometry Nodes* and translates them into a range of $0-1$, which are then colored in the shader (where it actually belongs) with a single material:

[image]

Comment: As soon as I'd written my answer, on second thoughts, considered this the better option. So many GN puzzles come down to interface / re-use. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want the info all in one material, and the range of polygon-shapes is unpredictable, maybe something along these lines, for re-use:

[image]

If you wanted a fixed correspondence between color and vertex-count, you could use a fixed input range for the *Map Range*, say, 3 -> 10, and clamp, so that all 10+  get the same color.

[image]

Comment: i tried your setup but it turns black i quadruple checked that i have exactly what you have in your images. I also tried different map ranges. [Where did i go wrong?](https://pasteboard.co/FufdUeTu41lV.png). Here's the [blend](https://blend-exchange.com/b/5qR9Gyed/)

Comment: Hi @HarryMcKenzie!. (BTW, I think [quellenform's method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/270026/35559) is better.. it's more general). I'm not sure it makes a difference, but, for stats, the _Index_ attribute is an integer, not a float? And .. obviously.. name the attribute referenced by the field 'Vx Count', 'vxc' in the GN modifier? .. Else, share file. :)

Comment: Hi @RobinBetts thanks for your quick reply! Yeah I noticed the *vxc* and tried *Vx Count* as well but was still black. This is my blend https://blend-exchange.com/b/5qR9Gyed/ just wanted to understand where I've gone wrong XD

Comment: You have to name the output attribute on the modified object so it can be picked up by the shader .. https://imgur.com/a/LkxbxOL

Comment: awesome! so that's the purpose of this output attribute so it can be used by the shader and possibly somewhere else. cool thanks alot :)

Comment: ... @HarryMcKenzie kind of slip I make all the time. (Distinction between [attribute field name] and [attribute name])